# Advanced 2-D Array map generation for 2D Platformer game with Java (processing)

Tags: java, arrays, multidimensional-array, processing

I'm trying to figure out a way to make my simple map generation better. So the question to be specific is, how do I make my random 2-D array platform generator, less random so it looks more like a platformer game level as well as adding a bit more variables to it for adding variation to each Map Generated. Explanation below.

Currently, I have this:

```java
void GenerateMap() {
  int x = width/30;
  int y = height/28;
  int[][] map = new int[x][y];
  //println(map.length);
  for (int i = 0; i < map.length; i++) {
    for (int j = 0; j < map[i].length; j++) {
      float val = random(0, 100);
      float nv = noise(val);
      println(nv);
      if (j <= (int) (.5 * map.length)) {
        map[i][j] = nv < .3 ? 0 : 1;
      } else if (j >= (int) (.7 * map.length)) {
        map[i][j] = nv < .6 ? 1 : 0;
      } else {
        map[i][j] = nv <= .3 ? 0 : 1;
      }
      println(i +"-" + j + " - rowcol: " + map[i][j]);
    }
  }
  levelMap = map;
  JSONArray saveArr = arrayToJson(levelMap);
  saveJSONArray(saveArr, dataPath("./maps/Generation_" + mapGenerations + ".json"), "compact");
}
```

It builds a 2d array with 1s and 0s, I tried to make it less random so it looks like a playable terrain. the top-most section will be 0's (air), the bottom-most will be 1's (platform). Then the middle will have a mix to make floating platforms and such. So far I've got nothing.

The next Idea that popped up was to have the number go from 0-N. This works by:
0 will always be air,
1 will always be a platform,
2 can be a platform of a different image, let's say a diagonal platform to form a slope off the edge
3 can be a collectible or anything
...etc

My issue is I can't figure out how to generate the numbers in a way that will make the map not look like a mess. I came up with a setup for my variables:

```java
  public int[] toplayer = null, // [0,0,0,0,...,0]
               bottomlayer = null, // [1,1,1,1,...,1]
               variation = {0,1,2}, // the 0-N
               variationRatios = {60, 30, 10}; // this would specify the frequency/probability of each variation show up, respectively, in a random() function
```

After all, that's done, then I run a function to replace all values with their respective "Sprite" and then display them on the screen.

```java
void drawPlatform(int amt, PVector pos, PVector size) {
  for (int i = 0; i < amt; i++) {
    //new Platform(new PVector(abs(width-((pos.x+(size.x/2)) + (i * size.x))), pos.y+(size.y/2)), size);
    Platform p = new Platform(new PVector(abs(((pos.x+(size.x/2)) + (i * size.x))), pos.y+(size.y/2)), size);
    if (platforms.indexOf(p) % 5 == 0  && !p.bouncy) {
      p.bouncy = true;
    }
  }
}

JSONArray arrayToJson(int[][] arr) {
  JSONArray ja = new JSONArray();
  for (int[] ar : arr) {
    JSONArray j = new JSONArray();
    ja.append(j);
    for (int a : ar) {
      j.append(a);
    }
  }
  return ja;
}

void LoadMap(int[][] map) {
  drawPlatform(width/30, new PVector(0, 0), new PVector(30, 30)); // top
  for (int i = 0; i < map.length; i++) {
    for (int j = 0; j < map[i].length; j++) {
      if (map[i][j] == 0) {
        new Platform(new PVector((i*30)+15, (j*30)+45), new PVector(30, 30));
        //drawPlatform(1, new PVector(i+j*30, (i+j)*30), new PVector(30, 30));
      }
    }
  }
  drawPlatform(width/30, new PVector(0, height-30), new PVector(30, 30)); // bottom
  println(gameObjects.size() + " GameObjects loaded");
  println(platforms.size() + " Platforms loaded");
}
```

Overall, this is how it's used:

```java
  GenerateMap();
  LoadMap(levelMap);
  mapGenerations++;
```

This is how it would end up looking (obviously different each generation):
[image: Generated Map Template]

But right now, I have something like this:
[image: Actual Generated Map]

I've looked everywhere for a couple of days now, for a solution and can't find anything as specific as my request. If you have any ideas, please let me know.

Quick Note: Of course, we could have the user write the array by hand but that's not time-effective enough. I could also have a visual map builder but that's a lot more code and more time than I have available. I am not opposed to this idea, however.